# How to pass an empty value to find_translation method in I18n gem in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

I'm working on a multi-language project. I'm using I18n gem for localization purposes. In some point I want to pass an empty value like following:

```
current_locale("")
```

Where the `current_locale()` function is

```
def current_locale(locale)
    if locale.empty?
      translation = find_translation(locale)
    else 
      translation = find_translation( I18n.locale ) || find_translation( I18n.default_locale ) || translations.first
    end
    translation.locale  
  end
```

But when the `current_locale()` function is called, it gives me following error:

```
undefined method `locale' for nil:NilClass
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: `find_translation(locale)` when locale is `""` returns `nil`. What is `find_translation` and what it should return on `""`?

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev: Well its a function in `has_translations.rb` class in `I18n gem`. Following is the function
`def find_translation(locale)
      locale = locale.to_s
      translations.detect { |t| t.locale == locale }
    end`

Comment: You see, in `find_translation` it converts locale to string and looks up for locale into `translations` enumerable and if doesn't find any -- returns `nil`. I guess it couldn't find anything for `""` locale.

Comment: So any work around can you suggest me to pass an empty value to current_locale()? Thanks

Comment: I think you shouldn't pass `""` as a locale (and actually, you can't do it, as I see the code). Try to rethink your algorithm and find out how to avoid passing empty locale in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Change the two first lines and it should work (as long as you have at least in `translation` in `translations`).

```
def current_locale(locale = nil)
  if locale.blank?
    ...
```

Comment: There are only two places in the code that can lead to a `nil` `translation`. First `find_translation(locale)` in line 3, but that would not be called if you check for `local.blank?` before. The second place is `translations.first`, if all other `find_translation` did not find anything. Therefore please double check if there is a `translation` in `translations.first`.